# Getting date of last aptitude upgrade

Tags: debian, aptitude

I updated the packages on a debian server a while back using aptitude but I cant remember the exact date when that happened. Is there a way to determine this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/20747/find-last-time-update-was-performed-with-apt-get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apt, aptitude and dpkg all keep logs in `/var/log/apt/`, `/var/log/aptitude` and `/var/log/dpkg.log` respectively. They rotate away after a while (6 months for apt and aptitude and 1 year for dpkg by default on Debian lenny).