# There is a log for update package lists?

Tags: linux, apt

I am looking for a log for something like "apt update", no "apt upgrade". Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that the apt update writes to a log.  You can see the last time it was run though.  Please see [Find last time update was performed with apt-get](https://serverfault.com/questions/20747/find-last-time-update-was-performed-with-apt-get).

Comment: That alright helps, thank you!